# Java GUI How to make an event when I press a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, calculator

I want to make a keyboard. If I press the button it has to come up at 2.(pic). I think it's a similar way to make a calculator. Can I have some advice?

Actually I don't even know if this right. Am I OK making a JButton like that?

[image]

This is my code.

```java
package assignment;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Random extends JFrame {
    Random() {
        setTitle("보안 키보드");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    showNorth();
    showCenter();
    showSouth();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(450,500);// 창크기를 정한다
    setVisible(true);}

    void showNorth() {
        JTextField area1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField area2 = new JTextField();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
    }

    area2.setText("보안문자를 입력하세요.");
    area1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    area2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    area1.setEditable(false);
    area2.setEditable(false);
    panel.add(area1);
    panel.add(area2);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

    void showCenter() {
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 5, 5)); 

// 버튼 생성하기
        JButton ba = new JButton("");
        JButton bb = new JButton("");
        JButton bc = new JButton("");
        JButton bd = new JButton("");

        JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");

        JButton er1 = new JButton("하나\n지움");
        JButton erall = new JButton("전체\n지움");

        p3.add(ba);// 버튼을 패널에 부착시킨다
        p3.add(bb);
        p3.add(bc);
        p3.add(bd);
        p3.add(b0);
        p3.add(b1);
        p3.add(b2);
        p3.add(b3);
        p3.add(b4);
        p3.add(b5);
        p3.add(b6);
        p3.add(b7);
        p3.add(b8);
        p3.add(b9);
        p3.add(er1);
        p3.add(erall);

        add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER); // 패널을 프레임의 중앙에 추가한다.
    }

    void showSouth() {
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        JButton complete = new JButton("입력완료"); // 입력완료 버튼 생성

        p4.add(complete);
        p4.setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Random();
    }

}
```

Comment: Add **action listeners** to your buttons.  Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information.

Comment: As @KevinAnderson said, you will need an `ActionListener` for user interaction with your components. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) Also, I suggest you create an _instance_ of the JFrame instead of _extending_ JFrame.

Comment: ... Some of your methods are outside of your class. Please format those.

Comment: Please put English for the comments and text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code needs extreme refactor. But as you the OOP beginner, lets dive into your problem. Your class called Random needs to implement ActionListener interface and override actionPerformed method:

```
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
```

Then, what you want to do is to add action listeners and set action commands for the buttons, for instance:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
button.addActionCommand("button")
```

Now you can know which button was clicked and represent something on your JTextField:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("button")){
        textField.setText("button was clicked");
    }
}
```